# How to use Model from Razor view in a script file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to send data from my Model to my scripts.
I did something like :

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
var data = model.Foobar;
```

It works in the view but I have to use this data in an external .js file.

Do you know how can I get data from my model in my scripts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load your model data on an input type hidden object, and load that data on your javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" id="yourParamName" value="@Model.whatever" />
```

Then, on your js code you just need to get that info

```
$("#yourParamName").val();
```

or without jQuery

```
document.getElementById("yourParamName").value;
```

The downside is that your model info will be on the client view, reachable by anyone... beware with what information do you post in this way.

Comment: Yeah that's what I also did. I don't really like it but it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the Razor syntax in a .js file, as the Razor engine isn't run on those files.

What you can do is either set up your javascript functions to either take a parameter of your Model data, or set up a javascript object that exposes properties that you can set with your Model data and runs the functions internally to the object. (Both the same idea, just one uses a higher level of closures.)

So in your javascript file if you just want to use a function parameter, you can do something like this:

```
var myFunction = function(razorModel) {
    // your javascript function steps go here.
};
```

Then in your view, you can have something similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { // If you're using jQuery, otherwise, just make sure this runs after you other javascript file gets loaded.

        myFunction(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action and view and only put javascript in it.

```
public ActionResult MyModelScript(int id)
{
    var Model = something;
    return View(Model);
}
```

Your View:

```
@model MyModelClass

function DoSomething()
{
    alert("@(Model.property)");
}
```

when using this view, treat it like a regular javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyModelScript/" + Model.id)"></script>
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but really kind of overkill, especially for what the user asked for.